# Installing docker on Raspberry pi

Tags: apt, docker

Trying to set up docker on my pi, getting errors I’m not sure what to do with. 
the generally recommended thing to do is to run the following:

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

But that script isn’t very informative error-wise; I’m getting the unhelpful:

```
sudo -E sh -c apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce >/dev/null
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I run that command directly from terminal:

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

About 80% through the installation I get the following troubling errors.

```
Building initial module for 4.19.66+
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.66+ (armv7l)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/aufs/4.19+20190211/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package aufs-dkms (--configure):
 installed aufs-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.2~3-0~raspbian-buster) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-18 19:15:09 CEST; 58ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6231 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6231 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u1+rpi1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10+rpi1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 aufs-dkms
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I’m uncertain where to direct my questions, so if this is not the right place, please point me in some better direction.

**Update:** If I run `sudo apt install docker.io` I get no errors in the install, but when I ran `sudo systemctl enable docker && sudo systemctl start docker` I get the following:

```
pi@node00:~ $ systemctl status docker.service 
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-18 19:50:48 CEST; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 11804 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11804 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 18 19:50:48 node00 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 18 19:50:48 node00 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 18 19:50:48 node00 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 18 19:50:48 node00 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 18 19:50:48
```

Comment: Try using the distro installer (`sudo apt install docker.io`).

Comment: On the above, I’ve updated the post.

Comment: Some Googling suggests there are several reasons that docker can break like this. Can you paste additional log output from journalctl -fu docker, /var/log/daemon.log, and /var/log/error.log? I think there may be some additional relevant logs scattered around, but I don't have a copy of docker available to check unfortunately.

Comment: What Raspberry Pi version do you use? Please address me with @Ingo otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 45):

In my case this problem was solved by rebooting after installing updates, and before trying to install Docker.

This will likely occur if you suddenly bring an older version of Raspbian up-to-date, and then straight away try to install Docker, as it appears some of the core binaries (or maybe even the kernel itself!) has been updated, the docker installer is reading those newer versions/files, but not seeing them in practice.

To be clear:

1. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -VV`
2. This is the important part: **`sudo reboot`**
3. Now (re-)install Docker; for example:

   1. `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh`
   2. `sudo sh get-docker.sh`

Comment: This was the fix for me. If you check your daemon.log you should see an error along the lines of:

`Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not installed`

which is caused by a kernel/lib update without a reboot. If you've already installed docker.io with apt, you can force a reconfigure, after a reboot (which will redo the correct systemd configuration) with:

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I joined the community just to upvote this answer, it solved the problem for me

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on a Raspberry Pi 4 with an SD card created with default Raspberry Pi OS (not lite or full) via the Raspberry Pi imager. Part #2 (sudo reboot) does indeed seem to be important!

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From a fresh install of `Raspbian Buster Lite (2019-07-10)` on a Raspberry Pi 4B I am able to reproduce OP's error by performing the following steps:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt install docker.io`

Omitting the `apt upgrade` leads to a successful install:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install docker.io`

For anyone who wants to see my errors:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install docker.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rpi.gpio-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cgroupfs-mount git git-man libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libltdl7 libmodule-find-perl
  libmodule-scandeps-perl libnspr4 libnss3 libproc-processtable-perl libsort-naturally-perl libterm-readkey-perl needrestart runc tini
Suggested packages:
  docker-doc aufs-tools btrfs-progs debootstrap rinse xfsprogs zfs-fuse | zfsutils git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el
  git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn needrestart-session | libnotify-bin iucode-tool
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cgroupfs-mount docker.io git git-man libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libltdl7 libmodule-find-perl
  libmodule-scandeps-perl libnspr4 libnss3 libproc-processtable-perl libsort-naturally-perl libterm-readkey-perl needrestart runc tini
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 220 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf docker.io armhf 18.09.1+dfsg1-7.1+rpi1+rpt1 [38.4 MB]
Get:2 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf cgroupfs-mount all 1.4 [6,276 B]
Get:3 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libltdl7 armhf 2.4.6-9 [387 kB]
Get:4 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libnspr4 armhf 2:4.20-1 [89.6 kB]                
Get:5 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libnss3 armhf 2:3.42.1-1+deb10u1 [942 kB]         
Get:6 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf runc armhf 1.0.0~rc6+dfsg1-3 [2,246 kB]           
Get:7 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf tini armhf 0.18.0-1 [169 kB]                      
Get:8 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libcurl3-gnutls armhf 7.64.0-4 [291 kB]             
Get:9 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf liberror-perl all 0.17027-2 [30.9 kB]                      
Get:10 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf git-man all 1:2.20.1-2 [1,619 kB]                              
Get:11 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf git armhf 1:2.20.1-2 [4,202 kB]                          
Get:12 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libintl-perl all 1.26-2 [756 kB]                     
Get:13 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libintl-xs-perl armhf 1.26-2+b3 [38.8 kB]                   
Get:14 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libmodule-find-perl all 0.13-1 [10.3 kB]                         
Get:15 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libmodule-scandeps-perl all 1.27-1 [44.0 kB]                     
Get:16 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libproc-processtable-perl armhf 0.56-1 [43.7 kB]                 
Get:17 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libsort-naturally-perl all 1.03-2 [13.5 kB]                      
Get:18 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libterm-readkey-perl armhf 2.38-1 [26.3 kB]                      
Get:19 http://mirror.web-ster.com/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf needrestart all 3.4-5 [57.4 kB]                                  
Fetched 49.4 MB in 51s (974 kB/s)                                                                                                      
Selecting previously unselected package cgroupfs-mount.
(Reading database ... 37646 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-cgroupfs-mount_1.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libltdl7_2.4.6-9_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnspr4:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnspr4_2%3a4.20-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libnspr4:armhf (2:4.20-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnss3:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnss3_2%3a3.42.1-1+deb10u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libnss3:armhf (2:3.42.1-1+deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package runc.
Preparing to unpack .../04-runc_1.0.0~rc6+dfsg1-3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking runc (1.0.0~rc6+dfsg1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tini.
Preparing to unpack .../05-tini_0.18.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking tini (0.18.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker.io.
Preparing to unpack .../06-docker.io_18.09.1+dfsg1-7.1+rpi1+rpt1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker.io (18.09.1+dfsg1-7.1+rpi1+rpt1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libcurl3-gnutls_7.64.0-4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:armhf (7.64.0-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../08-liberror-perl_0.17027-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17027-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../09-git-man_1%3a2.20.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.20.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../10-git_1%3a2.20.1-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.20.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libintl-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libintl-perl_1.26-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libintl-perl (1.26-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libintl-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libintl-xs-perl_1.26-2+b3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libintl-xs-perl (1.26-2+b3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-find-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libmodule-find-perl_0.13-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-find-perl (0.13-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-scandeps-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libmodule-scandeps-perl_1.27-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-scandeps-perl (1.27-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libproc-processtable-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libproc-processtable-perl_0.56-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libproc-processtable-perl (0.56-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsort-naturally-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libsort-naturally-perl_1.03-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsort-naturally-perl (1.03-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-readkey-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-readkey-perl (2.38-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package needrestart.
Preparing to unpack .../18-needrestart_3.4-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking needrestart (3.4-5) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:armhf (7.64.0-4) ...
Setting up runc (1.0.0~rc6+dfsg1-3) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17027-2) ...
Setting up libnspr4:armhf (2:4.20-1) ...
Setting up libmodule-find-perl (0.13-1) ...
Setting up tini (0.18.0-1) ...
Setting up libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-9) ...
Setting up libproc-processtable-perl (0.56-1) ...
Setting up libintl-perl (1.26-2) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.20.1-2) ...
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
Setting up libterm-readkey-perl (2.38-1) ...
Setting up libsort-naturally-perl (1.03-2) ...
Setting up libmodule-scandeps-perl (1.27-1) ...
Setting up needrestart (3.4-5) ...
Setting up libnss3:armhf (2:3.42.1-1+deb10u1) ...
Setting up docker.io (18.09.1+dfsg1-7.1+rpi1+rpt1) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-21 00:31:41 BST; 59ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5874 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5874 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
 installed docker.io package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libintl-xs-perl (1.26-2+b3) ...
Setting up git (1:2.20.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u1+rpi1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10+rpi1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker.io
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-21 00:31:49 BST; 16s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 7804 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7804 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xe
-- Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit docker.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1252 and the job result is done.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.socket: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.socket has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.socket has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit docker.socket has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1314 and the job result is done.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.socket has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit docker.socket has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1314.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1314.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1314.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1252 and the job result is failed.
Sep 21 00:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Sep 21 00:31:50 raspberrypi sudo[5519]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: By successful install do you mean that docker starts OK?

Comment: What Raspberry Pi version do you use?

Comment: By successful, I mean that docker installs without error and successfully performs a "hello world" test. Tests were performed on a Raspberry Pi 4 4gb.

Comment: So this isn't an answer, its an agreeance / 'me too' to the question? Not sure why this is here...

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested the installation on a Raspberry Pi 4B.

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install docker.io
```

on a fresh flashed [Raspbian Buster Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) without any problems. After the successful installation I get:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-09-19 19:34:18 CEST; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1161 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 30
   Memory: 34.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─1161 /usr/sbin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─1169 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level info

Sep 19 19:34:15 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:15.409128746+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
Sep 19 19:34:15 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:15.409839347+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Sep 19 19:34:15 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:15.410525448+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Sep 19 19:34:15 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:15.413664568+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 19 19:34:17 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:17.053724779+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Sep 19 19:34:17 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:17.467067691+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 19 19:34:18 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:18.144973027+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=4c52b90 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09.1
Sep 19 19:34:18 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:18.145878828+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Sep 19 19:34:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 19 19:34:18 raspberrypi dockerd[1161]: time="2019-09-19T19:34:18.828490882+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

So the problem you have is the underlying operating system. You should also use a fresh flashed Raspbian Buster.

Comment: Running Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye. Didn't have much luck with downloading and running the shell script. Seems to work with bullseye using the apt way. I did this after update, upgrade, dist-upgrade and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer by @smpita I also ran into this problem after doing the sequence of

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

before installing Docker. Investigating the logs for dockerd using `journalctl -xe` I found errors indicating that the kernel was missing certain required features. Checking `uname -a` and `ls /lib/modules/` I noticed that the versions of the kernel modules on my system were later than the kernel version. To rectify I ran:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This resulted in the kernel being updated to the latest version and now matching the version of the kernel modules. With this I can now successfully run `docker run hello-world`.

From the official documentation on [updating](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md):

> First, update your system's package list by entering the following
>   command:
>
> `sudo apt update`
>
> Next, upgrade all your installed packages to their
>   latest versions with the following command:
>
> `sudo apt full-upgrade`
>
> Note that `full-upgrade` is used in preference to
>   a simple `upgrade`, as it also picks up any dependency changes that may
>   have been made.

Answer (score 0):

On Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 11 Bullseye), I realise this has to do with `iptables` being deprecated in favor of `nftables`. Debian 10 Buster will probably fail too.

Docker daemon works for me by doing the following things:

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

This is based on https://wiki.debian.org/iptables.

Now reboot.

Then install with whatever means necessary:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```